# add a field to wordpress post

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to add an extra field in my Add Post ,
i added a field to wp_post that can be 0 or 1 
and then i wanna add check box into publish box in wordpress add post or edit post 
that checked when that field is 1 or unchecked when 0
and also it should can be save after submit update

I know that I can use Custom Field Templates, but the problem is that these custom fields insert the values into wp_postmeta and not wp_post, and I need everything for the single post in the same table.

actually i need to add extra field for using a query that retrieve some record that i need for converting to json and the read it not all posts, for application on android and ios

Comment: you shouldn't really modify the core wordpress tables - you should use the custom field templates.

Comment: i know , but i have to add a extra field to the table

Comment: why? this sounds like the XY problem.

Comment: actually i need to add extra field for using a query that retrieve some record that i need for converting to json and the read it not all posts, for application on android and ios

Comment: you could use a view joining the post meta field.

Comment: but there are lots of records and i think its gonna be to awful for loadding data if i use join 2 table

Comment: because its too large

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't modify the core table, as a lot of people already mentioned. You can do a select using join from both tables like that:

```
 $querystr = "
    SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'tag' 
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 'email' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_date < NOW()
    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
 ";

 $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

More about it here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query

Other than that, what exactly is your problem? To display a custom checkbox you can use [add_meta_box](http://codex.wordpress.org/add_meta_box) function. To update it you need to add your function to `wp_insert_post_data` hook and then insert your data to the database, something like that:

```
    add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'so27747402_save_data');

    function so27747402_save_data($post_san){
        global $wpdb;
        global $post;

        $checkbox = (isset($_POST['so27747402_checkbox']) && $_POST['so27747402_checkbox'] == 1);
        update_post_meta($post->ID, '_so27747402_checkbox', $checkbox);
        return $post_san;
    }
```

Or like that if you insist on doing it via changes to the core table:

```
    add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'so27747402_save_data');

    function so27747402_save_data($post_san){
        global $wpdb;
        global $post;

        $checkbox = (isset($_POST['so27747402_checkbox']) && $_POST['so27747402_checkbox'] == 1);
        $wpdb->query("UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET checkbox = $checkbox WHERE ID = $post->ID");
        return $post_san;
    }
```

But yeah, it's a pretty bad way. You should use `update_post_meta` instead.

Answer (score 0):

we have plugin for add custom filed to the post.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

1.crete a field

2.assign to post

Answer (score -1):

The best solve is Relwis's Meta Box plug-in for this. You can use it. [Source link](https://github.com/rilwis/meta-box)